# Laser print Mikraos Gedolos Tanach online?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, internet

Does a laser print Mikraos Gedolos Tanach or Nach exist online (for free)?

Update: Since there seems to be some confusion as to what I mean by "laser print" I will clarify my question. The new printing of most books nowadays had the letters sharp and uniform. The sentences are straight and sit on a perfect line. Older books have letters where the ink sometimes does not fill out the entire letter, letters are not exactly uniform, etc. Think of any siddur from about 20 years ago and Artscroll today, the perfect print of Artscroll is what I'm calling laser print (I know laser print could simply mean anything printed from a laser printer but in the vernacular laser print tends to mean a uniform, sharp consistent print). I'm looking for any version of the Mikraos Gedolos Tanach/Nach with the sharp perfect print.

Comment: the pdf's exist which you would have to download and print.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the pdf's?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/

Comment: I don't see any laser print editions.

Comment: as I stated, there are pdf's that you can download and print on your own laser printer.

Comment: @Danno that got a laugh (I hope that you're meant to be joking)

Comment: @Matt, I don't get how it's a joke. How can a laser-print edition exist online? You print it yourself. Am I missing something?

Comment: @msh210 - the OP want something of high quality "Laser printing is an electrostatic digital printing process that rapidly produces high quality text and graphics " as per en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_printing

Comment: @DannySchoemann I own a laser printer. I don't see the problem. One will not find a printed version online. One can either buy one that someone else laser prints or print one himself (unless he has a dot matrix or bubble jet printer).

Comment: @Danno - precisley what the OP wanted; an PDF of good (perfect) quality, not a scan from HebrewBooks - though their quality is usable, it's not "highest" quality. So if you're 100% sure there's no such thing online, then feel free to enter that as an answer.

Comment: Why did the question get down-voted?

Comment: @DannySchoemann My question would then be "what version fo the mikraot gedolot"? The torat chaim? Which meforshim? Not that I think there is one, but is the question asking for access to a specific thing or a general resource?

Comment: You might want to avoid referring to this as laser-print, as it may be somewhat misleading. Particularly over the last century, up until around the 1990s and even now, offset-printing was used because it was cheap (although often illegible) and the printer did not need to store large libraries of prepared stereotypes (or metallic type of any kind). What you are referring to would more accurately termed either as a phototypesetting process or as a digital typesetting process.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Thanks for the proper terms. I tried searching for what it's called but couldn't find anything. I called it laser-print because that is how I have heard people refer to that precise type of typesetting.

Comment: @Gabi, no problem. I don't know about online, but the Schulsinger Mikraot Gedolot on Chumash is letterpress, so it's also quite legible.

Comment: Does it have to be printer ready? Places like OYW and Sefaria have about a dozen different meforshim in text format allowing you to read the tanach text with the meforshim you want on your monitor.

Answer (score 3):

[mg.alhatorah.org](http://mg.alhatorah.org) is a text-based Mikraos Gedolos containing a huge number of Mefarshim (website options allow you to choose which ones you want to display).   It can be printed very clearly (laser print) straight from the page itself, or one can simply copy out the text to a word processor and print from there.

Comment: I cannot overemphasize how excellent a resource this is for Tanach study!